# Loop in XQuery repeats results several times

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I have a function which returns paragraphs from the text. So I'm comparing the `<anchor>` tag's attribute number(`@n`) to the `<notes>` tag's attribute number, if it's the same I want to print it with the tooltip if not I just want to print out the paragraph.

```
declare function letter:text_trans($node as node(), $model as map(*))
{
    let $resource := collection('/db/apps/Tobi-oshki/data')
    for $ab in $resource//tei:div[@type="translation"]/tei:ab
    for $note in $resource//tei:div[@type="notes"]/tei:note
    return
        if (data($note/@n) eq data($ab/tei:anchor/@n))
        then
          <div class="tooltip">{$ab}
            <span class="tooltiptext"> {data($note/@n)}.{$note}</span>
          </div>
        else
          <p> {$ab} </p>
    
};
```

In `<notes>` I have three notes and when it loops over the notes, each paragraph is returned three times.

How can I change it so it returns the paragraphs only one time?

I am using `xquery version "3.1";`

Comment: I don't see a reference to a `<notes>` node in the script provided (it appears some editing of the original question has made it less clear in this respect @mads-hansen).  While we can see your input XML is likely complex, it is difficult to address your question properly without a minimal example of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the for loop on the `$ab`, let a variable for the `$note` and select notes that have `@n` attribute values that match the `$ab`, then if there is a matching `$note`, use it, else return the `<p>` using just the `$ab`:

```
let $resource := collection('/db/apps/Tobi-oshki/data')
for $ab in $resource//tei:div[@type="translation"]/tei:ab
let $note := $resource//tei:div[@type="notes"]/tei:note[@n = $ab/tei:anchor/@n]
return
    if ($note)
    then
      <div class="tooltip">{$ab}
        <span class="tooltiptext"> {data($note/@n)}.{$note}</span>
      </div>
    else
      <p> {$ab} </p>
```

With this input:

```
<tei:doc>
  <tei:div type="notes">
    <tei:note n="1">note1</tei:note>
    <tei:note n="2">note2</tei:note>
  </tei:div>
  <tei:div type="translation">
    <tei:ab><tei:anchor n="1">translated note1</tei:anchor></tei:ab>
    <tei:ab><tei:anchor n="3">translated note3</tei:anchor></tei:ab>
  </tei:div>
</tei:doc>
```

the code above produces this output:

```
<div class="tooltip">
  <tei:ab xmlns:tei="tei">
    <tei:anchor n="1">translated note1</tei:anchor>
  </tei:ab>
  <span class="tooltiptext">1.<tei:note n="1" xmlns:tei="tei">note1</tei:note>
  </span>
</div>
<p>
  <tei:ab xmlns:tei="tei"><tei:anchor n="3">translated note3</tei:anchor></tei:ab>
</p>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering, I need to return not $note in the end but $ab (the paragraph) which doesn't have notes, in my case I have 5 paragraphs, and the 3rd and 5th have notes, others don't, so I need to return all of them but the ones with note need to be returned with the tooltip.
I used your way and added:      
`<p>{
for $mb in $resource//tei:div[@type="translation"]/tei:ab
    return
        if (data($note/@n) ne data($mb/tei:anchor/@n)) then
            " "
        else
           <p> {$mb} </p>  } </p>
`                     but it printed out paragraphs like 3,5,1,2,4

Comment: So, you want to return every `tei:ab` and conditionally provide tooltips if the `@n` matches a `tei:note`? it's much easier to assist if you can provide sample data and expected outputs, so that there is less guessing and chance for mis-interpretation